# Azure api app change access level

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I'm currently creating an api app in azure and want to change the  Access Level to Public (anonymous) like this:
[image]

However, what I get when I try to do that is this:

[image]

With nothing of the sort to be found.

What gives?

Answer (score -1):

Its under Features -> Authentication/Authorization. Scroll down a bit and you will find it.

[image]

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/ This explains recent changes.